# How can i get data on 1 hour basis

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

```
date_time                Data         Status

2015-04-15 17:40:20.0    18.5786        op

2015-04-15 16:20:59.0    16.7868        do

2015-04-15 16:20:55.0    24.58903       No

2015-04-14 16:21:00.0    24.289028      ok

2015-03-15 16:20:59.0    16.51689       dok

2015-04-16 16:20:55.0    24.789028      Nto

2015-02-15 17:55:59.0    28.784145      doq

2015-02-16 17:45:59.0   28.701414   dq

2015-04-18 17:15:59.0   25.784145   q

2015-04-10 15:15:19.0   21.784145   qq
```

Three coloumns are date_time,data and status and i want fetch all the data between 17:00:00-17:59:59hrs..that means i want to get 4 outputs.
i am trying by grouping but not getting it.
how can i get it?- any idea?

OUTPUT, that i want to get-=

```
date_time               Data      Status

2015-04-15 17:40:20.0   18.5786     op

2015-02-15 17:55:59.0   28.784145   doq

2015-02-16 17:45:59.0   28.701414   dq

2015-04-18 17:15:59.0   25.784145   q
```

Comment: mysql != oracle. please pick one. also, `select * from table where hour(date_time) = 17`

Comment: i am using oracle10g.

Comment: in oracle10g, hour is showing invalid identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might:

```
select ...
from   ...
where  to_char(date_time,'HH24') = '17'
```

Place an index on the expression to_char(date_time,'HH24') and you may get improved performance, but it depends on the distribution of values within the data.

If 1/24th of the rows meet the condition then an index might help, but if it's more like 1/12th then it's unlikely.

What might work in your favour is that if this is a logging table then the rows might have a low clustering factor on to_char(date_time,'HH24').

Don't rely on it though -- this may be a query that cannot be significantly improved through indexing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be neat if EXTRACT() worked but alas we can only extract time elements from intervals and timestamps, not dates.

```
SQL> select * from your_table
  2  where extract(hour from date_time) = '17';
where extract(hour from date_time) = '17'
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source


SQL>
```

**Update:**

Looking at the sample data you've posted you `date_time` might be a TIMESTAMP.  In which case EXTRACT() will work.  Check this out.

```
 SQL> select col1, date_time from your_table
   2  /

 COL1  DATE_TIME
 ----  ----------------------------
 ABC1  02-MAY-15 03.39.34.000000 AM    
 ABC2  30-APR-15 03.39.34.000000 PM
 ABC3  30-APR-15 03.39.34.000000 AM
 ABC4  28-APR-15 03.39.34.000000 PM

 SQL> select col1, date_time from your_table
   2  where extract(hour from date_time) = 3
   3  /

 COL1  DATE_TIME
 ----  ----------------------------
 ABC1  02-MAY-15 03.39.34.000000 AM
 ABC3  30-APR-15 03.39.34.000000 AM

 SQL>
```

However, all is not lost if your datatype is just a DATE.  n Oracle we can do arithmetic on dates. Truncating a date gives us the day at midnight.  We can then add a fraction for the time element, like this:

```
select * from your_table
where date_time >= trunc(date_time)+(17/24)
and date_time < trunc(date_time)+(18/24)
```

---

Note that such a query might perform badly if you have a large number of rows (it's a full table scan).  There are various solutions depending on your other business requirements.

In you need to run such a query often one approach would be to extract the time element.  In 11g or later you could use a virtual column and index that, but in 10g you can only use a function-based index.

```
create index your_table_time_fbi on 
    your_table(to_number(to_char(date_time, 'SSSSS')));
```

This uses the `SSSSS` date mask to extract the number of seconds from midnight.  To use the index you would need to change the previous query so it looks like this:

```
select * from your_table
where to_number(to_char(date_time, 'SSSSS')) >= (17*3600)
and to_number(to_char(date_time, 'SSSSS')) < (18*3600)
```

Comment: @AlexPoole - as it happens I had just noticed the formatting of the OP's data and I must have been writing it up while you were posting your comment :)